# Use of unresolved identifier 'UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration'

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, uicollectionview, configure

I just found this "Use of unresolved identifier 'UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration'" problem, it should be a standard way to construct the layout configuration, here is my code:

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    
    //this is where to alert use of unresolved identifier
    let configuration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: configuration)
    
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
    
    return collectionView
}()
```

can you please help?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` & `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` are operating system dependent apis. Which means you can not use them below there minimum operating system requirements.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above. These api is available from iOS 14.0+ (beta). And these api is shipped within Xcode 12.0+ (beta).

So In order to use this, you need to download Xcode 12.0(beta) from Developer [website](https://developer.apple.com/download/) or wait for the official App Store release.

Comment: But I am running in Xcode 12.1  and still, I am getting the same issue

Comment: @Shakti what ios deployment target version you have set on your project?

Comment: I have set 
iOS deployment target as 14.1
mac os  deployment target as 10.15.6